# How to center ImageView in a toolbar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, imageview, center, toolbar

Been trying to center a logo inside my toolbar. When i navigate to the next activity, the "up affordance" icon is present, and it will push my logo slightly to the right. How can I keep my logo at the center of the toolbar, without removing the up affordance icon?

This is my toolbar tag

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/primaryColor"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/app_bar_top_padding"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
app:theme="@style/CustomToolBarTheme">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_android_logo"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"/>
 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html), it says:

> *One or more custom views.* The application may add arbitrary child
> views to the Toolbar. They will appear at this position within the
> layout. If a child view's Toolbar.LayoutParams indicates a Gravity
> value of CENTER_HORIZONTAL the view will **attempt to center within the
> available space remaining in the Toolbar after all other elements have
> been measured**.

It means you cannot do it unless you create a custom `toolbar` or remove the `icon`.

Answer (score 15):

You can do it as following it works for me :

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/mainToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/headerLogo"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
            </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: pretty sure this won't work if you add menu items to the toolbar since that shortens the width of the RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 9):

You need to use the AppBarLayout widget with the Toolbar widget and setting the `contentInsetStart` to `0dp`. Otherwise the Toolbar will about 8dp of padding at the start (to insert the navigation buttons if needed)

Here's the working code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/company_logo" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Also, make sure you use `?attr/actionBarSize` as the height for the toolbar as this is the default actionBar height and will adjust to all the different screen sizes.

Answer (score 4):

You can do programmatically, that is the only way I've managed to fully center a logo in the toolbar.

Add to you activity:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus){

    // set toolbar logo to center programmatically
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
    ImageView logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
    int offset = (toolbar.getWidth() / 2) - (logo.getWidth() / 2);
    // set
    logo.setX(offset);

}
```

and your toolbar_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/bg_yellow"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:fontFamily="@string/font_family_thin"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@string/font_family_light"
        android:textColor="@color/text_dark_xxx"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_default"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" />



</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: i think this should be the accepted answer, nothing works but this !

Comment: Fails with menu items of differing sizes.

Comment: this should be accepted answer, when app bar is having only menu icon. Thanks for solution.

Comment: [@McGuile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1900721/mcguile) from the example above you can see that currently there's only a TextView and an ImageView, so if you are inflating a menu you'd probably have to measure the icons as well! Hint, maybe you could go into ***Tools > Layout Inspector*** to see what's really happening.

Answer (score 3):

I am bit late to answer this , but have wonderful solution

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">



    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:id="@+id/logoImageView"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/toolbar_background" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

and here is my toolbar_background.xml drawable

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/splash" android:gravity="center"
        />
</item>
```

[image: output here]

Answer (score 2):

Set the image as a background of the toolbar, not as a child view.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/detail_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:background="@drawable/my_image"
    app:theme="@style/CustomToolBarTheme">
```

Comment: With LayerList drawable http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList you can also set the background color by setting the logo as bitmap and putting a colored solid underneath it (on top on xml). That is if it's not set on the toolbar theme.

Answer (score 2):

For the devs who are using **vector drawable** or **SVG images**. 

This can be your background for toolbar, **drawable_toolbar_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/primary"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:width="@dimen/toolbar_app_icon_width"
        android:height="@dimen/toolbar_app_icon_height"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_app_logo"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</layer-list>
```

and **Yes, you have to fix the width and height of item inside drawable**, although the vector drawable is already having fixed size.

This is your toolbar view,

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/drawable_toolbar_background"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"/>
```

Comment: Somehow your solution does not work for me. The icon gets stretched to fit the width of the toolbar. Did you ever experienced that behaviour? This was the closed I found so far for vector drawables ...

Comment: @DominikusK. Yes, I did had this issue. That's why you have to fix the width and height of your item inside drawable_toolbar_background. I will highlight it.

Answer (score 0):

The **easiest** solution that works even with menu actions present is this:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/apbMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tlbMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
        app:navigationContentDescription="@null"
        app:title="@null"
        app:subtitle="@null"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnBack"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="12dp"
                android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:background="@null"
                android:onClick="onBackClickListener"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_navigation_back"
                android:visibility="@{showBackBtn ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE}" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/toolbar_icon" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the attribute **android:contentInsetStart** with **0dp** in the Toolbar.

```java
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    ...
    ...
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp">
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Kenan Begic, but i costumize it hehe.. Thanks to him.
If you have a Menu in yout toolbar, You need to add `app:contentInsetStart="50dp"` on your Toolbar.

Actually it doesn't have to be 50dp, but so far I'm using 50dp.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:contentInsetStart="50dp"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_main"
    app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.Travemates.PopupOverlay" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_travemates" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Example:

[image]