# How to insert a picture in navigation bar android

Tags: java, android, xml, navigationbar

[Navigation bar vs toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UckD2.png) i am trying to change my navigation bar a little bit. I want to insert a picture inside it and change the color but leave the back button there. What is the easiest way to do it? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center ImageView in a toolbar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28443786/how-to-center-imageview-in-a-toolbar)

Comment: Or perhaps this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33300978/how-to-add-image-in-toolbar

Comment: Sorry if i used the wrong word for navigation bar, tried that already and all i get is 1 more rectangle, i added the picture in my question as "Navigation bar vs toolbar" i want to add the picture where the main title is or the back button. Is that possible?

Comment: You need to use a Activity theme without a Toolbar. They are the same thing. Also called an ActionBar, by some

Comment: Thanks alot, you have answered my question!